# removing duplicate entries between different indexes in pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to pandas and would appreciate some help. Read the documentation but couldn't find a solution...

I have created a pd.Series (using groupby and applying two parameters). There are several thousand indexes, each with a set of codes (param_b). I am trying to remove codes that appear in more than one index.

I tried `drop_duplicates` but it did not do anything...

```
families = file.groupby("param_a")["param_b"].apply(set)
new_families = families.drop_duplicates()

an example, I have these three lines:
A    {5iv5, 5iv7}                                                                         
B    {5hx2, 2fl8, 2fl9, 5iv5, 5iv7, 2fkk}
C    {4lq8}
I want to remove the entries that appear in A and B (5iv5, 5iv7)
```

I used `apply(set)` to remove duplicates within `param_b`, and that worked, but I need to remove duplicates in different indexes as well.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post an example of your data and the expected result, it is not very clear

Comment: Edit your question and post it in your question with formatting pls

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want iiuc:

```
# import pandas as pd
# s = pd.Series({'A': {'5iv5', '5iv7'}, 'B': {'5hx2','2fl8', '2fl9', '5iv5', '5iv7', '2fkk'},'C': {'4lq8'}})

s2 = pd.Series()

for i in s.index:
    s2[i] = s[i].difference(set.union(*s[s.index!=i].values))

# A                          {}
# B    {5hx2, 2fl8, 2fl9, 2fkk}                  
# C                      {4lq8}
```

I'm not sure however if there isn't a more efficient solution.